# Wordpress DB MySQL enhancements for performance

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance

Our database team has suggested various improvements to the Wordpress DB that will bring up performance, such as changing BIGINT to INT, dropping some keys, etc. Will this be transparent to the Wordpress' usage of the DB layer?

Comment: Dropping keys to improve performance sounds like an *extremely* dubious strategy. Dropping keys can only help write performance, not read, and any benefit would typically be minimal, at best. More likely, read performance will dramatically suffer.  The theoretical benefit of changing `BIGINT` to `INT`, assuming it didn't break things, is also infinitesimally small.  You *might* get away with such changes, but it seems like a misguided effort to solve a problem that hasn't been properly identified.

Answer (score 0):

WP has a major flaw in that it uses a Entity-Attribute-Value schema.  On top of that, it chose poor indexes for one of the main tables -- postmeta.  I explain how to make significant improvements in *that* table.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta).  My recommendation includes decreasing by one the number of indexes for that table, but it is not simply dropping an index, rather redesigning the indexes.